# Override path variable in cmd

Tags: path, continuous-integration, gitlab

hey guys I hope you are doing well.

I have the following problem:
I have two different versions of the mingw compiler installed on my CI server.
This CI server has to do 2 jobs. The first job needs an other compiler than the second. 
The binaries of the mingw-compiler are stored in the path variable.
If I store both paths of the mingw compiler in the path variable it leads to errors because it doesn't know which binary to use.

So I want to override the path entries of the mingw compiler in the path variable at RUNTIME in the gitlab yml file.

How does it work? 
Do you have any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you considered trying before and after script?https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script-and-after_script